# model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, validation_data=(X_test, y_test) isn't working

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to write a simple neural network to classify dog breeds. Here is the link to the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/dog-breed-identification

This is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dogs = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Natha/Downloads/dog-breed-identification/labels.csv')

ImageHeight = 128
ImageWidth = 128
Depth = 3

from PIL import Image
import os, sys

path = ('C:/Users/Natha/Downloads/dog-breed-identification/train')
def resize():
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(item):
            im = Image.open(item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(item)
            imResize = im.resize((ImageHeight,ImageWidth), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(f + ' resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
            return imResize
resize()

X = dogs['id']
y = dogs['breed']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(ImageHeight, ImageWidth, Depth)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-bab577512e44> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    723     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    726             *args, **kwds))
    727 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3194     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3195     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3196         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3197             self._name,
   3198             self._python_function,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:754 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:998 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    C:\Users\Natha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:234 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_7 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)
```

These are the versions of the modules:

Keras: 2.4.2

Tensorflow: 2.4.0

Pandas: 1.1.3

I'm new at neural networks and whenever I try to do a project, this shows up when I try to train the model. If anyone knows how to fix this, please answer this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you have a shape with "None" on your last error line.  

When working with neural networks, I advise you to check often if the dimensions of your data is what you expect

Comment: Please give a self-contained minimal example of the error. It's rather rude to ask people to go download a dataset, adapt your code to actually run on their machines (you have hardcoded paths), and then sift through your code for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your data dimensions. Based on your model architecture, I expect that X_train to be shape `(n_samples,128,128,3)` and y_train to be shape `(n_samples,2)`. With this is mind, I made this test problem with random data of these image sizes and the model trained without any errors.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.rand(1000,128,128,3)
y_train = np.random.rand(1000,2)
X_test = np.random.rand(200,128,128,3)
y_test = np.random.rand(200,2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

With that in mind, print out the shape of your data to make sure it agrees with what you expect, and keep in mind that the shapes I used above worked properly.

Comment: Why do you have `sigmoid` in your last dense layer?

Comment: I just copied and pasted the original post's code for defining the model and just made sample data to show that it will work if they ensure the shape of the training data is correct. I made no suggestions to how the model is defined, just how they have to be careful in preparing the data to work with their model.